# Linking dataTableOutput and plot in Shiny in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, datatable

I am wanting to link a `dataTableOutput` and a plot within a shiny app, so that when a row or a cell is selected within the table, the plot will reactively update with the data associated with that row.

Here is my data:-

**Data**

```
#relevant libraries
library(wakefield)#for generating the Status variable
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(Pareto)
library(uuid)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)


#mock data creation
set.seed(1)
#data<-data.frame()
Date<-seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "1 day")
Date<-sample(rep(Date,each=10),replace = T)

event<-r_sample_factor(x = c("Wrestling", "Drama", 
                                    "Information", "Football", "Rugby", "Movie", "Music", "News"), n=length(Date))

channel<-r_sample_factor(x = c("Channel 1", "Channel 2", "Channel 3", "Channel 4"), n=length(Date))

Hour<-r_sample_factor(x = c(0:23), n=length(Date))

Group<-r_sample_factor(x = c("A","B","C","D","E"), n=length(Date))

#creating user ID

set.seed(1)

n_users <- 100
n_rows <- 3650

relative_probs <- rPareto(n = n_users, t = 1, alpha = 0.3, truncation = 500) 
unique_ids <- UUIDgenerate(n = n_users)

AnonID <- sample(unique_ids, size = n_rows, prob = relative_probs, replace = TRUE)


data<-data.frame(AnonID,Group,Date,Hour,channel,event)
data$Hour<-as.numeric(data$Hour)
head(data)
```

And here is my shiny app so far:-

**Shiny code**

```
#ui================================
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example panel"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("example text",
             sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                          dateRangeInput("daterange","Select dates", format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
                                         start = min("2015-01-01"),
                                         end = max("2015-01-10")),
                          numericInput("hourmin", "Select mininum hour",10,0,23),
                          numericInput("hourmax", "Select maximum hour", 22,0,23),
                          pickerInput("channel", "Select channel",
                                      choices = unique(channel), options = list('actions-box'=T,'live-search'=T),multiple = T)),#end of sidebarPanel
             mainPanel(
               column(width = 10, plotOutput("barplot", width = "100%")),
                      column(width = 8, dataTableOutput("table"))
             )#end of mainPanel
                          
             )
             )#end of tabPanel
  )#end of tabsetPanel
)#end of fluidPage


#server===========================================

server<-function(input,output,session){

  
 rv <- reactiveVal(NULL)  
  
  observe({
    
    rv(data)
  
    output$table<-renderDT({
      rv()%>%
        arrange(desc(Date))%>%
        filter(Date>=input$daterange[1] & Date<=input$daterange[2])%>%
        filter(Hour>=input$hourmin & Hour<=input$hourmax)%>%
        filter(channel %in% input$channel)%>%  
        group_by(channel,Date)%>%
        arrange(Date)%>%
        summarise(Programme=paste0(Hour,":",substr(event,1,3)), .groups = 'drop')%>%
        #mutate(rn=rowid(Date))%>%
        pivot_wider(names_from = Date,values_from = Programme) # %>%
      #select(-rn)
    })
    output$barplot<-renderPlot({
      
      rv()%>%
        filter(Date>=input$daterange[1] & Date<=input$daterange[2])%>%
        filter(Hour>=input$hourmin & Hour<=input$hourmax)%>%
        filter(channel %in% input$channel)%>%
        group_by(Date,Group)%>%
        summarise(UniqueID=n_distinct(AnonID))%>%
        ggplot()+
        geom_bar(aes(x=Date,y=UniqueID, fill=Group), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
        
      
    })
    
    })#end of observe
  }

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Which will give you this:-

[image]

What I want to do is be able to click on a row in the `dataTableOutput` (which is by Date and Hour) and then plot the number of unique `UniqueID` in the data which is associated with that date and time. What am I missing from my code that would allow me to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You want the `UniqueID` to be displayed on the plot or on the table? Your statement "plot the number of unique `UniqueID`" is not clear.  Please clarify.

Comment: Yes I would like the plot to show the count of the number of ```UniqueID```'s . At the moment, the plot shows the count of ```UniqueID```'s for filtered data specified by the ```sidebarpanel```. So when the row or cell in the ```dataTableOutput``` is clicked on, I would like the associated date and hour of that clicked row/table to be used as a filter for the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, we can use `reactiveValues` to hold the data from the rendered `datatable`.

```
rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
```

Second, we can use the possibility to select rows from a `DT` table.

```
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(rv$data, selection = list(target = "row"))
    })
```

Now all that remains is capturing the hours and dates contained in the resulting table and use that information to create de barplot.

Note that this table will contain the dates as column names and the hours contained inside a string because of how `pivot_table` was previously used.

[image]

Code:

```
# relevant libraries
library(wakefield) # for generating the Status variable
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)
library(Pareto)
library(uuid)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinyWidgets)

################### // UI //###################

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example panel"),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel(
      "example text",
      sidebarPanel(
        width = 4,
        dateRangeInput("daterange", "Select dates",
          format = "yyyy-mm-dd",
          start = min("2015-01-01"),
          end = max("2015-01-10")
        ),
        numericInput("hourmin", "Select mininum hour", 10, 0, 23),
        numericInput("hourmax", "Select maximum hour", 22, 0, 23),
        pickerInput("channel", "Select channel",
          choices = unique(channel),
          options = list("actions-box" = T, "live-search" = T),
          multiple = T,
          selected = unique(channel)
        )
      ), # end of sidebarPanel
      mainPanel(
        column(width = 10, plotOutput("barplot", width = "100%")),
        column(width = 8, DTOutput("table"))
      ) # end of mainPanel
    ) # end of tabPanel
  ) # end of tabsetPanel
) # end of fluidPage


################### // SERVER //###################


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)


  # TABLE -------------------------------------------------------------------

  observe({
    rv$data <-
      data %>% # data was created outside the shiny app meaning that is present in the global env
      arrange(desc(Date)) %>%
      filter(Date >= input$daterange[1] & Date <= input$daterange[2]) %>%
      filter(Hour >= input$hourmin & Hour <= input$hourmax) %>%
      filter(channel %in% input$channel) %>%
      group_by(channel, Date) %>%
      arrange(Date) %>%
      summarise(Programme = paste0(Hour, ":", substr(event, 1, 3)), .groups = "drop") %>%
      pivot_wider(
        names_from = Date,
        values_from = Programme,
        values_fn = as_mapper(~ reduce(., paste, sep = ","))
      )

    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(rv$data, selection = list(target = "row"))
    })
  })



  observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected, {
    req(input$table_rows_selected)

    # the dates i want are the names of the columns
    dts <- rv$data[input$table_rows_selected, ] %>%
      names() %>%
      `[`(-1)



    hrs <- # this will give me the hours present in the cells selected from DT
      rv$data[input$table_rows_selected, ] %>%
      map(~ str_extract_all(., "\\d+")) %>%
      `[`(-1) %>%
      reduce(c) %>%
      reduce(c)

    # i know that i need the first column only
    channel_values <- rv$data[input$table_rows_selected, 1] %>%
      pull(channel) %>%
      as.character()


    ###### BARPLOT #########
    output$barplot <- renderPlot({
      data %>%
        filter(Date >= min(dts) & Date <= max(dts)) %>%
        filter(Hour >= min(hrs, na.rm = TRUE) & Hour <= max(hrs, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
        filter(channel %in% channel_values) %>%
        group_by(Date, Group) %>%
        summarise(UniqueID = n_distinct(AnonID)) %>%
        ggplot() +
        geom_bar(aes(x = Date, y = UniqueID, fill = Group), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
    })
  }) # end of observe
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is precisely what I was needing, thank you!